# How to scroll until it hits the bottom, then reset to top?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Using `Winforms`, I have a `Datagridview` populated by data from my database. I refresh the `datagridview` every 5 seconds to reflect any changes made in my database.

I'd like to know how to scroll down a bit each time I refresh the `datagridview` until it hits the bottom. When it reaches the bottom, I'd like to reset the scroll back to the top.

Currently I have this code:

```
if(scrollPosition < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1 - 5)
{
    scrollPosition+=5;
}

else
{
    // the scroll value has already exceeded, reset to 0
    scrollPosition = 0;
}
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = scrollPosition;
```

The default value of my scrollPosition is 0 by the way

It scrolls down properly but it doesn't seem to reset back to the top. It doesn't go through my second if statement. I know I'm just missing some logic here. What am I doing wrong?

Update: Got it to work with the answer of huangda, and also updated my current code above, but it still seems buggy. There are times where it reaches the bottom already, but it doesn't scroll back to the top. I sometimes need to wait around 1 to 5 "+=5" more increments and then it will scroll to top aka fire the else statement.

I'd like to ask a follow up question. Is using dataGridView1.RowCount really the way to go in this situation? Or is there something better I could use to compare my scrollPosition with?

Answer (score 1):

There's a very obvious problem: `scrollPosition == dataGridView1.RowCount` may not be true if `scrollPosition` EXCEEDS `dataGridView.RowCount` since it gets grown by 5 each time.

Possible fix is to change "==" to ">=", which is:

```
if(scrollPosition >= dataGridView1.RowCount)
{
    //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know you can't get to the actual dgv scroll bar minimum/maximum and therefore you wont be able to set it.

if what huangda has suggested is ok then when your form loads get the **`FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`** value and when you want to reset it back to the top **`dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = value`**

edit
or just set `dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0`